# TFS maintenance job - 2 agnets with different versions in same pool

Tags: tfs, build-agent

I've configured the 2 build agents with the different version in single Agent pool to suit our developers.

I've configured the Maintenance Job in order to keep disk clean. Everything works properly for Agent 2, but old work files on Agent 1 are not deleted.

From the log:

> No agent found in pool DX which satisfies the specified demands:
>   Agent.Name -equals "Agent 1 name"
>   Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.114.0

It looks like the maintenance job will clean the work folders of an agent that are the same version. Does anyone have any idea how to proceed? Or is there any problem with our configuration?

Further details:

- Agent 1 Version 1.105.6
- Agent 2 Version 2.117.2
- TFS Version 15.117.26714.0

Comment: After some discussions we've decided to disable the old agent and use only the newer one. It was the easiest way how to solve this situation. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To narrow  down the issue you could try below configuration

- Agent Pool with two Agent 1 Version
- Agent Pool with two Agent 2 Version

This will narrow  down if the issue is related to your build agent version. Maintenance Job may not support with build agent version 1.

Besides, none of your build agent version is 2.114.0, why your log is trying find agent version 2.114. This also could be a cached related issue, please double check it.